# How to show Database table's grid using opensource Kendo Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I need to show my list from modal using open-source KendoUI Grid. But it is not success. I connect database and take data as list in controller class. I need to do this grid with taking data from database.

```
 $("#gridd").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "report/GetData",
                        type:"json"
                    }
                },
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false
                }, height: 430,
                selectable: "multiple",
                columns: [
                            { field: "Users.uName", title: "Kullanıcı", width: "80px" },
                            { field: "Locations.locName", title: "Oda", width: "80px" },
                            { field: "Devices.devName", title: "Cihaz", width: "80px" },
                            { field: "Commands.cName", title: "Komut", width: "80px" },
                            { field: "gasValue", title: "Gaz", width: "80px" },
                            { field: "tempValue", title: "Sıcaklık", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "humValue", title: "Nem", width: "80px" },
                            { field: "AlarmCodes.aName", title: "Alarm", width: "80px" },
                            { field: "ReasonCodes.rName", title: "Nedeni", width: "80px" }]
            }
        });
```

And my controller class

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    var reports = db.ActivityLog.OrderBy(c => c.dateTime).ToList();
    return Json(reports, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I edit my currently code. Now I see grid but I can't see data inside. How they will be showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found. It's work. I reorganize my controller side and view side. I wrote error in script datasource code. Now it's work.

```
<div id="grid" ></div>
    <div id="details"></div>
    <script>
        var wnd, detailsTemplate;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false
                },
                height: 430,
                selectable: "multiple",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                            read: "/Index/Getdata",
                            type: "json"
                        }
                },
                columns: [
                                { field: "username", title: "User", width: "80px" },
                                { field: "location", title: "Location", width: "80px" },
                                { field: "gas", title: "Gas Value", width: "80px" },
                                { field: "temp", title: "Temp Value", width: "130px" },
                                { field: "hum", title: "Hum Value", width: "80px" }]
              });
         });
```

My controller, In here respond data must be serialize. Thanks for everyone.

```
public JsonResult Getdata()
        {
            var reports = db.ActivityLog.OrderBy(c => c.dateTime).ToList();
            var collection = reports.Select(x => new
            {
                username = x.Users.uName,
                location = x.Locations.locName,
                gas = x.gasValue,
                temp = x.tempValue,
                hum = x.humValue
            });
            return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an Action in the controller of the view, and return it as a JSon object in the read method of the grid. The following code shows you and example by using Razor engine:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<System.Data.DataRow>()
        .Name("grdLocations")
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound("LocationId").Visible(false);
                columns.Bound("Name").Title("Nombre").ClientTemplate("<strong>#:Name # </strong>");
                columns.Bound("Latitude").Title("Latitud").Format("{0:n6}");
                columns.Bound("Longitude").Title("Longitud").Format("{0:n6}");
                columns.Bound("Altitude").Title("Altitud");
                columns.Bound("Comments").Title("Comentario");

                columns.Command(cmd => { }).Width(90);
            })            
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id("LocationId");
                model.Field("LocationId", typeof(int));
                model.Field("Name", typeof(string));
                model.Field("Latitude", typeof(decimal));
                model.Field("Longitude", typeof(decimal));
                model.Field("Altitude", typeof(decimal));
                model.Field("Comments", typeof(string));
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Location"))
        ))
```

as you can see, we have the ".Read()" which sets the action of the controller.

```
    public virtual ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(Location.GetList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.Handle(ex);

            throw;
        }
    }
```

The class "Location" has a static method which return a DataTable filled from your database. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: I have to do in javascript command. Is that possible model connect to javascript ? Because I can't use Html.Kendo() it gives syntax error.

Comment: Have you wrote '@' before "Kendo" if you are using Kendo engine and "%=" if you were coding with ASP... remember that the server code starts with this character. Furthermore, you have to resolve all logic in the class "Location" which is located in the model.